# "She doesn't remember reading such a text (before)"

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning, gerunds

> ***She doesn't remember reading such a text before.***

Does this sentence mean?

***She doesn't remember `when/the time` she's ever read such a text before.***

Or something else?

***Since the adverb "before" is awkwardly used here, I'll have to ask this question.***

***I would omit the needless "before" in the sentence.***

*Besides, I could add empathic meaning to the sentence:*

***She cannot remember `reading/having read` such a text.***

Comment: You missed a possible interpretation: *This is the first time she remembers reading such a text.* (Or: *At no time before now has she remembered reading such a text.*) In short, *before* could apply to her memory rather than to her reading. It's ambiguous.

Comment: So, the sentence in the title is ambiguous?

Comment: It *can* be ambiguous. I think most people would interpret it as you did. I was just mentioning another way it could be read.

Comment: @JasonBassford in what circumstances is it not ambiguous?  That it can be read in more than one way means that it *is* ambiguous.

Comment: @phoog Almost everything in the world *can* be ambiguous if you bend the odds of something being meant in a certain way beyond the realm of likelihood. But most things are never *taken* ambiguously.

Comment: @JasonBassford fair enough. I was just being (perhaps overly) sensitive to semantic diffusion, or whatever the phenomenon should be called that gives rise to phrases like "sufficient enough" or "step foot in."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely a situation where not remembering "such a text" is in reference not to memory, but to customary or standard expectations.

It most likely means that she has never read a text that was so different from her expectations. That is implied by using the word 'such.' It has a dozen or more meanings, but here I'm defining it as "of so extreme a degree or quality."

It's fairly common to use 'such' in that sense in the construction, "I don't remember [*gerund*] such a [*noun*] before;" e.g., "I don't remember seeing such a fight before," "I don't remember hearing such an argument before," etc.

And in this case, 'before' is used as an *adjunct*: it is not necessary to make the clause or sentence complete or grammatically correct, but it adds extra meaning. In this case it connects earlier events to the moment of speaking. You're right that it can be removed, but that doesn't necessarily make it awkward or needless.

In this case, it seems to be saying "She doesn't remember reading such a [stupid, confusing, etc.] text before [this moment in time]."

The implication is that this is one of the most unusual texts she has ever read.

Links:

[M-W - Before](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/before)

[M-W - Such](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/such)

[Cambridge Dictionary - Uses of 'before'](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/before)

[Cambridge Dictionary -Adjuncts](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/adjuncts)

Comment: It doesn't seem like you have understood my question. With that being said, it doesn't mean your answer isn't good, it's rather fine. But you do prefer to avoid usage of the adverb "before" while in this case, by replacing it with the adverb "ever" so that we could avoid ambiguity. Am I right?

Comment: I may have misunderstood exactly what you were trying to find out. I was answering the question, "Does this sentence mean she doesn't remember the time she read such a text before." This would imply that she *has* read such a text and just doesn't remember. But I don't think that's the intended meaning; hence my answer. But I'll amend it to address your excellent point.

Comment: @Alex Raw - I hope I haven't made things worse by rewriting the answer. And you are correct: you could leave off 'before' and add 'ever,' or say, "She cannot remember reading such a text," and the meaning would not be dramatically different; it just has a slightly different emphasis.  But the original sentence is fine as it is, and the use of before, even at the end of a sentence, doesn't need to be avoided.

Comment: Thank you for providing such an answer! That was what I wanted to know.

Comment: But why does @JasonBassford in the comments above say it's ambiguous? I do agree with you, yet I want to know why he's said that. I know this is not my question, but rather it is a comment.

Comment: Moreover, what about this variant? "She cannot remember ever reading such a text before.";

Comment: Or, better: "She cannot remember reading such a text ever before(now)."

Comment: @Alex Raw - This keeps getting complicated, doesn't it? I'll give you my interpretation, but first I want to make clear I'm not trying to argue with Jason Bassford. In the case of his first comment, the use of the word 'before' to link two time periods (please see the links I added to the post) makes it mean exactly what he describes as an alternative interpretation. If she doesn't or can't remember, then this is the first time she has read such a text, as far as she knows. I don't disagree that it could refer to memory, I just don't think that's what's intended. So that does add ambiguity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107227/discussion-between-fremont-the-boy-bug-and-alex-raw).